# Make content go over large border

Tags: css, border

I have the following rules:

```
.borderedCanvas{
    border-width: 89px 95px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(/images/canvas_bg.png) 89 95 repeat stretch;
    -moz-border-image: url(/images/canvas_bg.png) 89 95 repeat stretch;
    border-image: url(/images/canvas_bg.png) 89 95 repeat stretch;
    width: 700px;
}
.borderedContent{
    margin: -60px;
    width: 820px;
    display: block;
}
```

And the following html:

```
<div id="login" class="borderedCanvas">
  <div id="loginBox" class="borderedContent">
    <form>
    ...
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

It creates a ~90px wide border around the div I apply it to. Now I want that every content inside borderedCanvas divs gets expanded to inside the border 60px. This is because although I had to use ~90px, the real border appears as if it is only 20px. I tried the adding the following rule to *.borderedCanvas* it had no effect: *padding: -60px*;

Comment: can you show your html also ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, don't forget that you're using CSS3, and while you're using CSS3 you can use CSS2. And CSS2 have pseudo-elements and all other juicy things!

So, you can achieve the thing you want without any extra elements just by using pseudo-elements like `::before`!

So, there is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UxJ8H/

The things worth mentioning:

1. See how you can use negative `z-index` on a pseudo-element with positive on the element itself to put the pseudo-element user the content.
2. With CSS2 you can set the `left`+`right` and `top`+`bottom` values for absolute positioning at the same time, so you can position the pseudo-element like you want.

So, combining pseudo-elements with border-image and positioning you can active a loooot of effect just like this easy.

Comment: This breaks if the combined width or height of the borders on the pseudo-element is larger than the total corresponding dimensions on the content element. In that case, the border appears to extend beyond the edges of the content element, regardless of the sizing applied to the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2):

Negative padding does not work... Padding is the inner-fill of an element, not the outer. Use margin: -60px instead.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it does not work. Content keeps not growing over the border. added more info to the question.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-image-outset

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564699

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=497995

this will be shipped in next revisions of browsers, and will work like a negative padding, but only relative to border-image, and only if border-image is supported

with negative margins, in fact, you will break appearance in older browsers!

for now you need to insert, as you do, a wrapper element inside the bordered content:

```
<div class="borderimg">
    <div class="fixpos" style="margin:-20px;">
        your content here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for the clarification but the suggested wrapper with negative margin workaround is what I am using and it is not working.

Comment: @JhonnyEverson please provide a jsfiddle of the issue (with the image too!)

Comment: turns out that in my code, I did not isolated the html/css well enough. Something must been causing problem. When I isolated the code in fiddle ( without all other css I was using, including bootstrap.css,  the solution worked.) Thank you.